# whats does mean my eyes need to be ok

Tags: idioms

I just heard this phrase on `stackoverflow` chat. English is not my native language and I don't understand what it means. I tried to translate it on Google translator to understand, but the translation doesn't make sense.

> Wish I can help more but I got work tomorrow and my eyes need to be OK.

[StackOverflow Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36552120#36552120)

Comment: You need to copy the sentence or part of the text where you heard this from.

Comment: Sounds a little bit like someone had typed a comment and expects you to read it again.

Comment: Without context, I would assume it means she needs some sleep, or to sober up

Comment: please provide the link or context

Comment: I've added a link to the chat I believe the OP is referencing. If this is incorrect, please feel free to update with the correct quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the context of this quote, and your conversation with the poster:

> Wish I can help more but I got work tomorrow and my eyes need to be ok.
>
> [Source](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36552120#36552120)

Combined with the posters earlier comment:

> am about to go sleep
>
> [Source](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36552054#36552054)

The implication is that they need to get some sleep before they go to work tomorrow.

---

I believe this boils down to the fact that if you are tired, or suffer from sleep deprivation, often your eyes feel "tired", or fatigued.  Often, eye fatigue is attributed to staring at computer screens for long periods of time without breaks:

> Your eyes might get tired easily if you stare for long periods at a computer, smartphone, or game console. The eye doctor might call this computer vision syndrome or digital eye strain.
>
> [Source](http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/eye-fatigue-causes-symptoms-treatment#1)

Its not (in my opinion) an overly used phrase (certainly I rarely hear it). I would expect its usage to be limited to situations where your eyes are *already* fatigued, and you need to spend a period away from the source of the irritation, or if the task you are referring to is on that might exacerbate eye strain.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Nice first answer.